# Can't delete my account from the past

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I wanted to delete my account from [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) because I don't use the site and wanted to have a 'clear out'. I used the contact form and requested a deletion link and it was sent through and all was well, so I thought.

However, I went on my profile to check the status and I've now seen that it says that my account will be deleted in *40 minutes ago*.

So unless I need to travel in time, I suspect something has gone wrong.

What's happened?

[image: Picture of account deletion.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The job that deletes accounts runs periodically (once every hour, I think). So unless your account was scheduled to be deleted *just an instant prior to* the job running, there'll always be some period of time less than an hour where you'll be able to see a message like that.

By the time I got to this post, your account had already been deleted.

Comment: Yeah it's gone now, thanks for the information.